# Good application design where database/tables changes are frequent

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, application-design

In a microsoft development environment ie. .net, c#, sql server, entity framework etc. : what is the best design for an application where there is frequent addition of tables and columns to tables in the underlying database due to business requirements.

The problem with using ORM/Entity framework in this context is that you've to update your model, recompile and re-deploy the application which can be painful + if there are simple to complex data validations required on these new columns being added you have to carefully write code at the right places as well.

Just trying to find if there's an easy and efficient way to use the power of ORM and not create SPs for every little thing.

---

Part 2 of same question:

Why can't I tell an ORM that I want to use these tables(or an entire database) and it then generates classes at run-time. I know things won't be strongly typed because of that. There are obvious drawbacks to that biggest one being design time/compile time errors won't occur as much as in strongly typed design forcing you to write less buggy code (or at least save lot of time because of that).

But this will at least solve the following problem:

- It will fetch all columns from db (including new columns)
- You don't have to compile, deploy because of small changes

Now if there's an easy way to implement a good design using ORM or something that facilitates this design, please let me know. Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to answer without examples. I would normally argue that is either a broken business side or a broken design to start with. I can not envision a business with that frequent changes, so really an example is needed. Alternatively to property bags you could always work with code generation - nothing says the compilation has to happen in your computer, it can happen in the background in the data editor, i.e. on application level.

Answer (score 4):

Ever and frequent widening of database schemas lends itself to maintenance nightmares as you suggest. Instead consider a vertical approach. For example, envision a schema mapping table in which each new record represents a new property for that entity. Whenever a new property (which would in essence be a new column on a horizontal table structure) is needed, it is simply created as a new record.

```
PropertyID(PK)      PropertyName
1                   ID
2                   Name
3                   Description
4                   LastModDate
```

A second table would hold entity instance records

```
InstanceID      PropertyID(FK)  PropertyValue
1               1               1
1               2               Target Field
1               3               Minnesota Twins baseball stadium
1               4               1/15/2013 12:00:00 PM
```

Your C# model then would hold a list of generic property objects representing instances of your entity. The list of properties and their values for a specific entity would be populated at runtime from the entity's instance records.

```
public class EntityInstance
{
    public int InstanceID { get; set; }
    public List<InstanceProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class InstanceProperty
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

This approach enables expansion of your data model schema without having to regenerate entities constantly or, worse yet, add specific new properties to your managed code every time in order to consume them.

We've been quite successful in implementing a highly configurable rules engine for our vast product line which then drives the options, workflows, and behaviors of several independent applications used throughout the company. My examples above are a bit trite, but they serve to suggest the point.

Again, the key is thinking "vertically" as opposed to "horizontally."

Comment: Property bag, yes - the classical antipattern but very useful at times. Still I can not envision the busienss case. Last time we used it was for stuff like tagging, or "extended properties" in a CMS.

Comment: Good point, we leveraged the property bag in our early SharePoint days too. The case I'm referring to involves being able to add new products, along with their defined rule structure, in an extensible fashion. My example above was vastly over simplified in comparison to our actual rules engine architecture, which allows for property values to serve as ancestors for further properties, effectively enabling a dynamic hierarchy of rule dependencies on a per-product basis.

Comment: Ok, so that are then pretty much extended properties in a catalog / shop scenario? Property bag approach, flat out, unles you want to go code generation, but without support for inheritance IN sql server that also will turn problematic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine

Answer (score -1):

In such environment try to keep each table independent,
i means don't have many relationships among the tables.
We are also facing same problem and for this we are following 
AGILE methodology.
This link will help you 
[Agile to have change](http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html)